# How do I enable 132x50 text mode for console instead of 80x25?

Tags: grub2, console

What parameters do I have to set in `/etc/default/grub` in order to boot by default in 132x50 and verbose.

Comment: For verbose, I think you simply need to take "quiet" out as a boot option; I don't know if that's done in /etc/default/grub or the scripts in /etc/grub.d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most authentic sources on kernel parameters can be found in the kernel tree under the name `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`, an online version can be found at [the GitHub mirror of Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt).

- Verbosity can be controlled by the `quiet` parameter, removing it will increase verbosity.
- The resolution can be set with the `vga` parameter, possible values are documented in the [TLDP framebuffer HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/x168.html). For example, if you'd like the boot resolution to be 1024x768 with 24 bits color depth, the parameter should be set like `vga=0x318`. The actual character count can be determined by taking the kernel font size into account.

Answer (score 1):

I used two parameters in /etc/default/grub:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768x24
# bug workaround
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

I found the second item by reading the shell scripts in /etc/grub.d.

Be sure to "set pager=1" before running vbeinfo so you can read the output.

Be sure to run "sudo update-grub" when you are done